# c# WPF окна из другого пользователя

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, users

Я работаю над библиотекой для одной Windows программы на .Net 4.7.2
Как оказалось у программы есть еще "фоновая" версия, которая работает как служба от имени собственного пользователя ShadowUserProg .

Моя библиотека выводит окошки, к примеру возьмем окно авторизации
в логах которые находятся в `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\ShadowUserProg \...` (Программа сама их пишет) я вижу что вызвано окно, но визуально я его не вижу. Я полагаю что окошко вылезло у скрытого пользователя ShadowUserProg который использует программа для работы в фоне.

И так выходит вопрос, как открыть WFP окно у другого пользователя, а не от которого запущена библиотека/программа ShadowUserProg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38057721/12888024 оно?

Comment: Еще стоит убедиться, разрешено ли взаимодействие службы с UI, быть может проблема вообще не в пользователях.

Comment: По идеи, если бы было запрещено, то я получила бы ошибку... Хотя кто его знает. Проверю и ссылочка вроде что-то похоже, попозже проверю, спасибо большое.

Comment: Там есть галочка "разрешено взаимодействие с рабочим столом" у службы, без нее окна работать не будут